# In a if statement how to concatenate all the messagebox in only one? c#

Tags: c#

I have a if statement that prints a messagebox everytime it loops and i want it to print only once, in this case, when the loop ends. And i want to concatenate every information that was printing before in only one messagebox.

Thats my code:

```
private void PrintInOrder(Node node) //   In-order
    {
        string nome = "";
        bool flag = false;
        //do
        //{
        //    PrintInOrder(node.lChild);
        //    Console.WriteLine(" " + node.value);
        //    nome += node.value;
        //    PrintInOrder(node.rChild);
        //} while (node != null);
        if (node != null)
        {
            PrintInOrder(node.lChild);
            //Console.WriteLine(" " + node.value);
            //nome += Environment.NewLine + node.value;    

            PrintInOrder(node.rChild);
            flag = true;
        }
        if (flag) MessageBox.Show("" + node.value);

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?   Something like this should work... 
Create a variable to hold the message.  Concatenate that each time it is called, and then when it's all done, display it.

Comment: Try this :             List<TextBox> messageBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 };
            string message = string.Join(",", messageBoxes.Select(x => x.Text));

Comment: @jdweng why would he want a List of TextBox, whatever that even is? That's so completely irrelevant

Comment: To make the code simple.  The textboxes could have names (instead of 1,2,3,4) where the order would not be correct.  Also have a list is much faster than searching through controls by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something similar to this???

```
private void PrintInOrder(Node node, ref string currentLogMessage)
{
    string nome = "";
    bool flag = false;        
    if (node != null)
    {
        PrintInOrder(node.lChild, ref currentLogMessage);            
        PrintInOrder(node.rChild, ref currentLogMessage);
        flag = true;
    }
    if (flag) currentLogMessage += node.value + " ";
}

/*****************************************/

var logMessage = "";
PrintInOrder(myNode, ref logMessage);
MessageBox.Show(logMessage);
```

Comment: It worked, but is not printing in alphabetic order :( nvm managed to do it to work, thank u alot.